# what does + sign in superscript of the variable mean?

Tags: notation

I came across the following when reading 'Recommender systems' textbook written by Charu C. Aggarwal, and I am curious what it means:

[image: this]

$u_{iq}$ is an unknown variable and it is part of the
[gradient descent algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBfuq.png).

Can anyone explain to me what superscript + mean in this context?

Comment: Maybe the new value computed from the previous one?

Comment: $u_{iq}^+$ is just a temporal variable used to store the new value of the variable $u_{iq}$ before it can actually be assigned to that variable itself (this can't be done immediately because we still need the old value of $u_{iq}$ to calculate the new value for $v_{jq}$ in the next line).

Comment: Thank you so much!